# TIMESCALEDB schema issues

Tags: go, timescaledb

I'm trying to create columns in timescale db to match my type struct in GoLANG. Below is my type struct and the code for my tables/hyper tables. Does anyeone know what im doing wrong?

```
    type Trade struct {
    A int16     `json:"a"`
    B int16     `json:"b"`
    Ev string   `json:"ev"`
    P int16    `json:"p"`
    Sym string  `json:"sym"`
    S int16     `json:"s"`  
    T int64     `json:"t"`
}




creatX  := `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb;`
creatT  := `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trade (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, a INT, b INT, ev TEXT, sym TEXT, s INT, t INT, p DECIMAL);`


//Table schema 
tradeHypertable := `CREATE TABLE trade_data (
    time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    a INT NOT NULL,
    b INT NOT NULL, 
    ev TEXT NOT NULL, 
    sym TEXT NOT NULL, 
    s INT NOT NULL, 
    t INT NOT NULL, 
    p DECIMAL NOT NULL
    );
    SELECT create_hypertable('trade_data', 'time', 
    a INT,
    b INT, 
    ev TEXT, 
    sym TEXT, 
    s INT, 
    t INT, 
    p DECIMAL if_not_exists => TRUE);
    `
```

I am getting this error Unable to insert sample into Timescale ERROR:

```
syntax error at or near "INT" (SQLSTATE 42601)
exit status 1
```

There are probably many issues here, please educate me.

Comment: I am new to timesacledb. But I notice that you are representing `P` field in struct as an `int16` but the tables have `p DECIMAL`. Is this expected?

Comment: Check syntax of [`create_hypertable`](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/create_hypertable/). You only provide table name, which it's column is the time partition column. You don't provide columns to this functions, since they discovered from the original table.

Comment: @advayrajhansa I will correct that. As for right now its just an int.

Comment: @k_rus I do select from the relational table, the columns, though, right?

Comment: You need to run just `SELECT create_hypertable('trade_data', 'time')` after the create table statement. Do I understand correctly that you get the error for your create hypertable statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
tradeHypertable := `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trade_data (
    time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    a INT, 
    b INT, 
    ev TEXT, 
    sym TEXT, 
    s INT,
    t BIGINT, 
    p DECIMAL);
    SELECT create_hypertable('trade_data', 'time'); 
    `

trdInsert := `INSERT INTO trade_data (time,  a, b, ev, sym, s, t, p) VALUES  ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)`
```

trdInsert is the right syntax